# ExoPlayer force showing bottom bar

Tags: java, android, exoplayer

Seems like ExoPlayer won't show bottom bar (exo_bottom_bar) on some phones -- only progress bar line is visible.

Is there a way to force full bottom bar with icons to show there?

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zl0T6.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can make call View.Visible on initializing playerView or increase the ratio of of playerView (buttons can not fit).

`playerBinding.exoplayerBottomBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE`